# What issues might we have using query parameters in a REST service to designate which parent/child links should be returned?

Tags: json, rest

Lets say you have a set of resources which look like:

```
/v1/API/Events
/v1/API/Transactions
```

where Events look like:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"blah",
    "date":"2010-01-11",
    "duration":1231231,
    "transaction_id":3
}
```

except that the transaction_id can be left out or set to null

Transactions look like:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"transaction_name",
    "date":"2015-01-01"
}
```

Now here is the issue, there are some times where it would be beneficial to be able to get a Tranaction and it's events at the same time. It would definitely be beneficial to be able to `POST` a Transaction with it's events. i.e.

```
{
    "name":"new_transaction_one",
    "events": [
       { 
           "name":"blob",
           "date":"2010-01-01,
           "duration":10
       },
       { 
           "name":"blob_2",
           "date":"2010-01-010,
           "duration":15
       },
    ]
```

and it would also be useful to be able to make a `GET` request like:

```
/v1/API/Transactions/1?withEvents=Y
```

Other options would be to have another resource:

/v1/API/TransactionsWithEvents

But if you have objects with several different sets of child records, you would have to have a lot of different combinations. I also don't like that they have different paths event though we are talking about the same resource.

I'm leaning towards using query parameters in the `GET` request but I'm wondering if there are any gotchas.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a case where typical RESTful API scaffolding reaches it's limits.  It would probably be preferable to create some convenience methods (especially for POST) that can work across the different resources, for example, creating a transaction and associated events in a single POST.  You will find that most any service with a relative level of complexity needs to have the convenience methods to prevent the user from having to (using same example) create the transaction, read the transaction id from response, then create events, then create transaction to event relations.

Tying it back to your example, that may mean you have a method like

```
POST /v1/API/CreateTransactionWithEvents
```

You may not need similar convenience endpoint for the case of returning events with transactions, as I think your parameter string approach may make sense here since you are just enriching the data returned from the record with related events.

```
GET /v1/API/Transactions/{ID}?withEvents=1
```

This is a bit more of a gray area and really subject to what works best within your other API's (so you are not doing something totally different), with providing clear API to clients, etc.

Just think of typical resource-related endpoints (i.e for Transactions and Events) as the main backbone for your RESTful service, with adding convenience methods as appropriate to address specific resource CRUD use cases that are not easily handled by backbone endpoints. This could be cases where you want to prevent client from making a series of API calls to get to something you might provide in a single call, or when you need to do something like atomically added records across resources with a single API call.

Comment: If GET /v1/API/Transactions/{ID}?withEvents=1 is reasonable, I'm not sure why having a similar parameter for POST requests is not. I'd like to avoid having paths which are not resources.
For instance, I'd rather go with POST /v1/API/TransactionImport/, but that seems clunky. It comes down to trying to avoid the n+1 problem you have with databases. If you request a list of resources, lets say all the transactions that have a name that starts with 'A', and you need the events associated with each transaction, I don't want to have to iterate over those transactions to make a GET request to Events

Comment: @bpeikes For POST requests, you typically don't use query string parameters at all.  Your POST data payload could consist of all transaction and event data that you are wishing to create. You would not want to create a transaction and then events separately as you mention. The problem you mention is exactly why you want to utilize convenience methods that can work across resource sets. For GET you could as easily go with a convenience method as well - something like `GET /v1/API/TransactionWithEvents`.  That is really up to you whether you want to expose a separate endpoint for that use case.